# How to identify and label similar rows in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a large data set that is composed of two panda data-frames.  One of which is the measurements taken from an instrument, the other is the variables present at each measurement.  The goal is to use a few supervised learning methods to predict the variables given the measurements.  I have not found a way to use multiple variables as the 'label' or y value in any supervised learning methods I have had experience with, such as scikit learn's random forest classifier.

As a work around, I am trying to predict only one or two variables at a time by essentially making a new column that indicates similar rows.   This way I can feed in only one variable that actually represents two into the learning method

What I begin with:

```
   a    b
0  1  103
1  6  103
2  1   103
3  2   2
4  3   103
5  6   103
6  1   103
7  5   103
8  1    2
9  2    2
```

What I want:

```
   c    
0  1
1  2
2  1
3  3
4  4
5  2
6  1
7  5   
8  6
9  3
```

If you know how to do supervised learning with multiple label or y variables, that would also be quite helpful.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking here.  It's unlikely that you'll get a good answer until you describe your problem a little better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is **not** a *we-write-your-code* service, you have to show some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your question really needs clarifications but since they are MIA i will assume ahead.

**ASSUMPTIONS**

- The column on the left comes from a list of lists. I will name that "alist_oflists".
- Every time a unique inner list is found, a new integer-type identifier is attributed to it.
- The output can simply be a list of lists again with the inner ones being single item lists containing the IDs found earlier. The order of the two lists must match.

---

```
alist_oflists = [[1, 1000], [2, 10], [2, 100], [2, 10], [3, 1000], [2, 100], [2, 10]]

# we need tuples instead of lists cause lists are not hashable (will be used as dict keys)
alist_oftuples = [tuple(x) for x in alist_oflists]

print(alist_oftuples) # prints:[(1, 1000), (2, 10), (2, 100), (2, 10), (3, 1000), (2, 100), (2, 10)]

a_dict = {}
i = 1
for items in alist_oftuples:
    if items in a_dict.keys():
        continue
    else:
        a_dict[items] = i
        i += 1

i_wanna_see_results = []
for item in alist_oftuples:
    i_wanna_see_results.append(a_dict[item])

print(i_wanna_see_results) # prints: [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2]
```

Is this what you wanted to have?